# Is it a good practice to put two components into one feature folder in Redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, directory-structure

Let's say I have a feature of `userStats` and I want to use one data (from `userStatsSlice`) in two different components, `Balance` and `Debt`. Is it considered a good practice to put `Balance` and `Debt` components into `userStats` feature folder instead of one `UserStats` component?

I'm referring to the code structure officially recommended by [Redux Toolkit docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure/#what-should-my-file-structure-look-like-how-should-i-group-my-action-creators-and-reducers-in-my-project-where-should-my-selectors-go) and that's the one I'm using.

Thanks in advance!